# Whats Wrong with my OpenGL

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, opengl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [12.04 and NVIDIA card problem with NVIDIA Geforce 7025](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131508/12-04-and-nvidia-card-problem-with-nvidia-geforce-7025)

Something is wrong with my OpenGL after my 12.04 upgrade

All OpenGL apps run slowly. Including but not limited to Google Earth,glxgears,Draftsight e.t.c

My graphics card: Nvidia Zotac 6200

This is my glxgears output

```
amith@amith-desktop:~$ glxgears
12 frames in 5.2 seconds =  2.299 FPS
12 frames in 5.3 seconds =  2.272 FPS
12 frames in 5.3 seconds =  2.257 FPS
11 frames in 5.0 seconds =  2.195 FPS
```

This is my /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[    26.953] 
X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
[    26.953] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[    26.953] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server i686 Ubuntu
[    26.953] Current Operating System: Linux amith-desktop 3.2.0-24-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 25 08:43:52 UTC 2012 i686
[    26.953] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic root=UUID=3bf6821b-1d5b-4b44-8257-91f2631f7c34 ro crashkernel=384M-2G:64M,2G-:128M quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    26.953] Build Date: 04 April 2012  11:58:38PM
[    26.953] xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[    26.953] Current version of pixman: 0.24.4
[    26.953]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[    26.953] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    26.953] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed May  2 21:11:36 2012
[    26.954] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[    26.954] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[    26.954] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[    26.954] (**) |-->Screen "My Screen" (0)
[    26.954] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[    26.955] (==) No device specified for screen "My Screen".
    Using the first device section listed.
[    26.955] (**) |   |-->Device "My Card"
[    26.955] (==) No monitor specified for screen "My Screen".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[    26.955] (==) Automatically adding devices
[    26.955] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[    26.955] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[    26.955]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    26.955] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[    26.955]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    26.955] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[    26.955]    Entry deleted from font path.
[    26.955] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[    26.955] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[    26.956] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[    26.956] (II) Loader magic: 0x4595a0
[    26.956] (II) Module ABI versions:
[    26.956]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[    26.956]    X.Org Video Driver: 11.0
[    26.956]    X.Org XInput driver : 16.0
[    26.956]    X.Org Server Extension : 6.0
[    26.957] (--) PCI: (0:0:2:0) 8086:2582:1462:7131 rev 14, Mem @ 0xd3000000/524288, 0xb0000000/268435456, 0xd3080000/262144, I/O @ 0x0000e400/8
[    26.957] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0221:174b:2017 rev 161, Mem @ 0xd0000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, 0xd1000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[    26.960] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[    26.960] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[    26.984] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[    26.985] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.985]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.985]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    26.985]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[    26.985] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[    26.985] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[    26.985] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    26.985]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    26.985]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    26.985]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    26.985] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[    26.985] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[    26.985] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so
[    27.135] (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    27.135]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.135]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    27.135] (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:49:54 PDT 2012
[    27.135] (II) Loading extension GLX
[    27.135] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[    27.138] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[    27.139] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.139]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.13.0
[    27.139]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[    27.139]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    27.139] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[    27.139] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[    27.140] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[    27.141] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.141]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.142]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    27.142] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[    27.142] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    27.143] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    27.144] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.145]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    27.145]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    27.145] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[    27.145] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[    27.145] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    27.148] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[    27.148]    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.148]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[    27.148] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  295.40  Thu Apr  5 21:29:50 PDT 2012
[    27.148] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[    27.148] (++) using VT number 7

[    27.149] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[    27.149] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[    27.150] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    27.150] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.150]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.150]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    27.150] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[    27.150] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[    27.150] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    27.150] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    27.150]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.0.0
[    27.150]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[    27.150] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[    27.151] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[    27.151] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[    27.151] (II) Loading /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
[    27.151] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[    27.151] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[    27.151] (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "My Screen" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[    27.151] (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
[    27.151] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[    27.151] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[    27.151] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[    27.151] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "NoLogo" "True"
[    27.151] (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
[    27.151] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[    29.071] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0): Display (Samsung SA300/SA350 (CRT-0)) does not support NVIDIA
[    29.071] (II) NVIDIA(GPU-0):     3D Vision stereo.
[    29.073] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce 6200 (NV44) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[    29.073] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 524288 kBytes
[    29.073] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 05.44.a2.11.00
[    29.073] (--) NVIDIA(0): Interlaced video modes are supported on this GPU
[    29.073] (--) NVIDIA(0): Connected display device(s) on GeForce 6200 at PCI:1:0:0
[    29.074] (--) NVIDIA(0):     Samsung SA300/SA350 (CRT-0)
[    29.074] (--) NVIDIA(0): Samsung SA300/SA350 (CRT-0): 400.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[    29.074] (**) NVIDIA(0): Using HorizSync/VertRefresh ranges from the EDID for display
[    29.074] (**) NVIDIA(0):     device Samsung SA300/SA350 (CRT-0) (Using EDID frequencies
[    29.074] (**) NVIDIA(0):     has been enabled on all display devices.)
[    29.074] (II) NVIDIA(0): Assigned Display Device: CRT-0
[    29.074] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    29.074] (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    29.075] (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
[    29.075] (==) NVIDIA(0): 
[    29.075] (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated modes:
[    29.075] (II) NVIDIA(0):     "nvidia-auto-select"
[    29.075] (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1600 x 900
[    29.082] (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (92, 91); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
[    29.082] (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
[    29.082] (--) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[    29.103] (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "nvidia-auto-select"
[    29.199] (II) Loading extension NV-GLX
[    29.285] (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
[    29.285] (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store disabled
[    29.285] (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
[    29.286] (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
[    29.286] (II) Loading extension NV-CONTROL
[    29.286] (II) Loading extension XINERAMA
[    29.286] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[    29.286] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[    29.287] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[    29.287] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    29.287]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 1.2.0
[    29.287]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 6.0
[    29.287] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[    29.287] (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
[    29.287] (==) RandR enabled
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XTEST
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension SYNC
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension SECURITY
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension RENDER
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension RANDR
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
[    29.287] (II) Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
[    29.300] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[    29.384] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[    29.395] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    29.395] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    29.395] (II) LoadModule: "evdev"
[    29.395] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    29.400] (II) Module evdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    29.400]    compiled for 1.11.3, module version = 2.7.0
[    29.400]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    29.400]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 16.0
[    29.400] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    29.400] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    29.400] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    29.400] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event1"
[    29.400] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    29.400] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    29.400] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    29.400] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input1/event1"
[    29.400] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    29.400] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    29.400] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.400] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    29.401] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    29.401] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    29.401] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Power Button'
[    29.401] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    29.401] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    29.401] (**) evdev: Power Button: Device: "/dev/input/event0"
[    29.402] (--) evdev: Power Button: Vendor 0 Product 0x1
[    29.402] (--) evdev: Power Button: Found keys
[    29.402] (II) evdev: Power Button: Configuring as keyboard
[    29.402] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0"
[    29.402] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    29.402] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    29.402] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.402] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[    29.403] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Optical USB Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[    29.403] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    29.403] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech Optical USB Mouse'
[    29.403] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    29.403] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: always reports core events
[    29.403] (**) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event3"
[    29.403] (--) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc016
[    29.403] (--) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    29.403] (--) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[    29.403] (--) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Found relative axes
[    29.403] (--) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[    29.403] (II) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[    29.403] (II) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[    29.403] (**) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    29.403] (**) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    29.403] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1.1/3-1.1:1.0/input/input3/event3"
[    29.403] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Optical USB Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 8)
[    29.403] (II) evdev: Logitech Optical USB Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[    29.407] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    29.407] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    29.407] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    29.407] (**) Logitech Optical USB Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    29.408] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech Optical USB Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    29.408] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    29.408] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    29.408] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event2)
[    29.408] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[    29.408] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    29.408] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[    29.408] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[    29.408] (**) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Device: "/dev/input/event2"
[    29.409] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Vendor 0x1 Product 0x1
[    29.409] (--) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Found keys
[    29.409] (II) evdev: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Configuring as keyboard
[    29.409] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2/event2"
[    29.409] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    29.409] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[    29.409] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    29.409] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[   262.405] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-03AF3717FF3AB439A4BAABA686CCB40771CDF520.xkm
[   262.413] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-03AF3717FF3AB439A4BAABA686CCB40771CDF520.xkm
[   267.908] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.484] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.512] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.519] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.526] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.532] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.539] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.545] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.552] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.558] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.566] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.572] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.578] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.585] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.592] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   269.598] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-2320486FA1F45B423A1EB1AFC5F5271CBA16F9C3.xkm
[   799.413] [mi] Increasing EQ size to 512 to prevent dropped events.
```